# Parse/Display nested JSON array with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am looking to pull data from a job board API. I'd like to have headings for the departments (pulled from JSON level 1) and under each department the current open positions (JSON level 2). I have tinkered with this 50 different ways and ran through all the related articles I can find, but just can't quite get the dominoes to fall in my brain.

**Update**

I have gotten pretty close, but I'm obviously missing how to loop this correctly. It repeats every department and job instead of nesting all of the jobs under the department header once.

Fiddle to see where I am at - https://jsfiddle.net/swampfox/f6jv204x/#&togetherjs=GjcUL090zr

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/agilityrobotics/departments',
    data: {
      check: 'one'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(key, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
          $.each(value[i].jobs, function(k, v) { // Second Level into Jobs
            $('#jsonpResult').append(
              $('<h3>' + value[i].name + '</h3><p class="cat"><a class="joblink" href="' + v.absolute_url + '"> ' + v.title + '</a></p>')
            );
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jsonpResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you output the `h3` for each job, but it should only be output once per iteration of the *outer* loop (not the *inner* loop).

I would also use more jQuery style for creating the elements, and I would use `async`/`await` to flatten a bit the "callback hell".

```js
$(async function() {
    let {departments} = await $.getJSON('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/agilityrobotics/departments');
    $("#jsonpResult").append(
        departments.flatMap(({name, jobs}) => [
            $("<h3>").text(name),
            ...jobs.map(({absolute_url: href, title}) =>
                $("<p>", { "class": "cat" }).append(
                    $("<a>", { href, "class": "joblink" }).text(title)
                )
            )
        ])
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jsonpResult"></div>
```

To exclude departments for which there are no jobs:

```js
$(async function() {
    let {departments} = await $.getJSON('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/agilityrobotics/departments');
    $("#jsonpResult").append(
        departments.flatMap(({name, jobs}) => jobs.length ? [
            $("<h3>").text(name),
            ...jobs.map(({absolute_url: href, title}) =>
                $("<p>", { "class": "cat" }).append(
                    $("<a>", { href, "class": "joblink" }).text(title)
                )
            )
        ] : [])
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jsonpResult"></div>
```

Comment: Any suggestion for integrating some kind of if/then logic on the outer loop. IE if there is nothing in the inner loop ( no jobs), don't display that department?

Comment: Thank you! This is a huge step in getting me to the finish line. It's so elegant.

Comment: Added a version to my answer which excludes departments that have no jobs.